# Sticky physics body in Sprite Kit

Tags: sprite-kit

In my Sprite Kit app I would like to have a sticky physics body: any dynamic body which comes in contact with this body does not bounce, but stays connected to it instead.

Is there any property that performs this sticky behaviour? If not, how can it be achieved?

Comment: you can try to set spriteNode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO; when a body have a contact with the static body

Comment: But then if the sticky body moves they won't remain connected, right?

Comment: I have not tried it so I'm not sure about this but it should work as you said

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no property of SKNode or it's subclasses that will allow you to make a physicsBody 'sticky'. However, you could simulate something like that yourself using one of the following suggestions:

1 - Add the other body as a `child` of the sticky body on contact. This will make the other body move with the sticky body when it moves.

2 - Create a `SKPhysicsJoint` between the two bodies on contact. This will connect the two bodies together. Read up on SKPhysicsJoint [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsJoint_Ref/Reference/Reference.html).